# Program crashing when Trying to free Bytes from heap

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

In my program here, I am trying to take a full heap, send it to another function, create a new heap of larger size, copy over values from old heap, free the old heap and return the new heap to continue to be used. However when I try to free the heap I run into a bus error. To my understanding, I am to free this old heap, and the new heap should continue and take the place of the old heap in this implementation, until it too needs to be renewed. I tried to change the heap being freed, but that made no difference. Additionally, I tried to do without the "grades = arr " line as that only copies the address of arr and wouldn't do much, but it does allow my program to run a bit longer before crashing so I opted to leave it in. Any help with this would be appreciated. for context, grades is the original heap and is originally allocated 40 bytes of memory.

```
void gradeScanner(int gradeCount, int allocCount, double* grades)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 5) {
        scanf("%lf", &myGrade);
        if (myGrade > 0 && i == 4) {
            *(grades + gradeCount) = myGrade;
            gradeCount++;
            allocCount++;
            printf("%s", "stored ");
            printf("%lf", myGrade);
            printf("%s", "in the heap at ");
            printf("%p\n", (void*)(grades + i));
            printf("%s", "heap at ");
            printf("%p", (void*)(grades + i));
            printf("%s\n", "is full");
            expander(grades, gradeCount, allocCount);
            i = 0;
        }
        else if (myGrade > 0) {
            *(grades + gradeCount) = myGrade;
            gradeCount++;
            printf("%s", "stored ");
            printf("%lf", myGrade);
            printf("%s", "in the heap at ");
            printf("%p\n", (void*)(grades + i));
            i++;
        }
        else if (myGrade < 0) {
            i = 5;
            average(grades, gradeCount);
            evaluator(grades, gradeCount);
        }
    }
}

double* expander(double* grades, int gradeCount, int allocCount)
{
    int x = allocCount * 40;
    double* arr = (double*)malloc(x);
    printf("%s", "Allocated ");
    printf("%d", x);
    printf("%s", " bytes to the heap at ");
    printf("%p\n", (void*)arr);
    printf("%s", "copied ");
    for (int i = 0; i < gradeCount; i++) {
        printf("%s", "hiya");
        *(arr + i) = *(grades + i);
    } //for
    oldAlloc = x;
    grades = arr;
    free(grades);
    printf("%d", gradeCount);
    printf("%s", " grades from ");
    printf("%p", (void*)grades);
    printf("%s", " to ");
    printf("%p\n", (void*)arr);
    printf("%s", " Freed ");
    printf("%d", oldAlloc);
    printf("%s", " byes from the heap at ");
    printf("%p\n", (void*)grades);
    return arr;
} //expander
```

Comment: suggest learning about the function `realloc()`

Answer (score 0):

```
grades = arr;  
free(grades);
```

is out of order. The program leaks the old `grades` array by pointing `grades` at the new array and then releases the new array.

```
free(grades);
grades = arr;
```

will release the old `grades` array and then point `grades` at the new array.

Note: What follows is guesswork.

I suspect `gradeScanner` should look more like this:

```c
void gradeScanner(int gradeCount, int allocCount, double* grades)
{
    while (true) // keep going until user inputs bad grade 
    {
        if (scanf("%lf", &myGrade) == 1) // got a valid input from user
        {
            if (myGrade >= 0) // got a valid grade
            {
                if (gradeCount == allocCount) // array full. expand it
                {
                    allocCount++; // strongly consider expanding by more than one 
                                  // memory allocation and all the copying is expensive.
                                  // Unless you have memory constraints, it's better 
                                  // to waste a bit of memory in order to do fewer
                                  // reallocations and copies.
                    expander(grades, gradeCount, allocCount);
                }
                *(grades + gradeCount) = myGrade; // store the grade
                gradeCount++;
            }
            else // didn't get a valid grade
            {
                average(grades, gradeCount);
                evaluator(grades, gradeCount);
                return; // done scanning grades
            }
        }
        else // user didn't input a number
        {
            // clean up bad input and request a new one
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So I had given this solution a shot as well, it results in an "invalid next size (fast) " error, after 3 successful allocations. Would this maybe be a sign that the issue is in the way I am calling this function, in addition to the error with grades = arr; being first?

Comment: Unfortunately that other bug could be anywhere. There are a lot of unknowns here, like  where did `myGrade` come from? Recommendation: Make a [mre] (MRE). Making a MRE isolates a bug in so little space that you usually spot the mistake and fix it yourself. When you can't, you have a nice tight little piece of code  that (hopefully) has one-and-only-one bug that you or others can experiment with until the bug is spotted and squished.

Comment: in `if (myGrade > 0 && i == 4)` the hard-coded 4 seems strange. Since this is the branch that expands the array, I'd expect `allocCount` instead of 4.